# SURF algorithm implementation in C#

Tags: c#, computer-vision, surf, aforge

I need a way of tracking objects in a video feed. I use [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) to capture a video from webcam and plan to use [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) for object detection in each frame. But I can't figure out how to:

1. Compare the surf data to other surf data.
2. Find an implementation (in c#) of computing SURF points, not in accord or aforge or any library aside from opencv (where all the examples are c++).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [***this***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjxWpKCQqJc) fantastic resource.

This is SURF implemented via the OpenCV C# port called "EMGU"

Hope it helps.

Comment: That video is about visual basic

Comment: Yes, sorry EMGU is ported to C# and the functions are almost identical, so if you know what functions are avaliable to you, re-creating it in C# should not be difficult

Answer (score 0):

To calculate SURF you can use Accord as it is easy to implement. Need any help regarding this kindly visit following link.

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector.htm

To compare the SURF data with another SURF kindly watch this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95453/Automatic-Image-Stitching-with-Accord-NET

Comment: kindly see the second link

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon, please add some context around the links!

Comment: [Feel free to read this FAQ, paticulary the seciton titled **Provide context for links**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)